# Check buttonIndex for the second UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have 2 alertView in a method and I want to check the button index of the second alertView. How can I do it? I want to get the buttonIndex for the else condition. Below is the code I am trying to do.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick{

    NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xyz.com"] encoding:NO error:nil];

    if(connect == NULL) {        
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:@"Please check your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];        
        [alert show];               
    } else {    
        UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upload to the server?" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"CANCEL",nil];    
        [alert1 show];        
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        My functionality
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is having the alert view's instances global and checking those in the alertview's delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //  assuming the myAlert2 is your alert's instance
    if (alertView == myAlert2)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Or you can just give tags to your alert and then checking the tags in the alertView's delegate method, like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 2)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        { 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say it is better advice to 'store the alertViews in a property', rather than 'make them global'. Otherwise agreed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag for alert view

eg :

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"hai" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

alert.tag = 1;

[alert show];
```

then you can check like below

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        { 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```